# Hold input=date value in HTML after submited button in table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I searched a lot but maybe because I am quite new here i couldn't fine a result that's works for my challenge.

**Project view** 
[image: Project view]

**What's is going on:**
I have made page where users could click on a date-picker, after the user selected a date or a date range and they click on  the submit button "Verzenden"the table that is positioned under the selection area shows all data from that specific date or date range that is available in the database.

In this table the user is able to adjust some data from a specific table row. 
After clicking on the submit "Ok" button the changes the user made is pushed to the database.

**Now my challenge:**
After the user has changed some data from a row an they click on submit button "Ok" i want to achieve that the user is getting back to it's last date selection that he made before adjusting some data in a row table. What is the best way to handle this ?? I hope someone could help me, thanks already for participating and reading.

Comment: Why don't you use ajax and update only the rows effected after the response looks fine ?

Comment: use localstorage, and save date each time value change, and on dom ready search for the date value in localstorage and give it to your date input

Comment: try to hold the date range value in the URL like "page.php?to=12-06-2016&from=26-08-2016" and on the page load put these values in input box

Comment: Gatsbill do you have an example how you will do this? I tried this morning to put it in localStorage but i didn't get a satisfied result.

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is "pre-populating a form".  You can pre-populate the form with PHP by generating HTML that has the value written directly in the HTML

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($someValue, UTF8, ENT_BOTH);?>">
```

Your homework probably wants you to save the input into the user's SESSION, and then check the SESSION every time you render the page.  If a previous value is in the session, then pre-populate the form (i.e.  render the HTML with the hard-coded values).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form autocomplete="on">...</form>
```

the "autocomplete" attribute allows you to save your selection that you've submit after reload the site.
If you don't want this feature take effect for some special tag,you should write your code like this:

```
<form autocomplete="on">
    ...
    <input type="date" autocomplete="off" /> // this tag won't save the choice
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9nfz311z/

html part:

```
<input type="date" name="test"/>
```

js part :

```
var dateInput = document.querySelector('input[name="test"]');
var DOMReady = function(a,b,c){b=document,c='addEventListener';b[c]?b[c]('DOMContentLoaded',a):window.attachEvent('onload',a)}

// on change save in localStorage the value
dateInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  localStorage.setItem(dateInput.name, dateInput.value);
});

// on dom ready if localStorage has date value apply it to the input
DOMReady(setDateValue);

function setDateValue() {
  var date = localStorage.getItem(dateInput.name);
  if (date) {
     dateInput.value = date;
  }
}
```

Comment: I post my code could you tell me why this doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks this worked great it gives back the date now into the date field.  Is  their an extended option to let submit the datepicker form automatically after the click ok in the table?

Comment: depends what your form do on submit, if it's ajax or not

Comment: It's only Posting data by now using a PHP script that pushing data in MYSQL database. I just discovered your solution form yesterday will work in chrome but not in IE browser do you have an idea?

Comment: should be better, but anyway I won't make code for IE < 9, it's not supported anymore, and it's holding web in a bad state, if you really need it, check for dom ready function, or use jquery